# Image scaling in Windows Forms looks worse on Widows XP than it does on Windows 7

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, windows-xp

I have a Windows Forms application written in C# / .NET 4 that includes a `Button` control with an `BackgroundImage`. The image used is larger than the button, but the `BackgroundImageLayout` property is `Zoom` so that it's scaled to the size of the button.

On Windows 7, the image looks fine. However, on Windows XP the image looks terrible. It looks as though it has been scaled simply by dropping lines.

Can anyone confirm that this is the expected behaviour, and whether there's anything I can do to fix the appearance on Windows XP other than by scaling the image myself and using the scaled version in the button?

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: scale on yourself.

Comment: could be a number of reasons why there is a difference... screen resolution/color depth, video card...

Comment: @Don: I've ruled out color depth (it's set to full color), and video card (I can reproduce it in a VM). And it happens across a variety of machines. The common factor is the OS.

Comment: not that it may make a difference, but have you ran dxdiag to compare/contrast any differences in the video output of the machines?

Comment: "I can reproduce it in a VM" isn't a very good hint, a VM typically emulates a video adapter in a low-color mode setting.  Focus on the value you get for e.Graphics.InterpolationMode in, say, a Paint event handler.  Nothing much you can do when you get a low quality value, other than just scaling the image yourself.

Comment: I agree with Hans, rendering the image yourself will give you much more control over the quality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only speculate that on Windows XP GDI system does scaling using simpler interpolation algorithms. Can't find anything to confirm my guess though.

If you decide to go for manual scaling you can take code and info from these links:

- http://www.christian-etter.de/?p=283
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2941/Resizing-a-Photographic-image-with-GDI-for-NET
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11143/Image-Resizing-outperform-GDI

Another far guess - try enabling visual styles on your controls by including manifest in your application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289524%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I somewhat agree with this statement, there is a lack of GDI acceleration on XP vs. 7 due to the fact that win 7 uses more complex GPU acceleration... One solution could be to drop winforms entirely and stick with WPF as its DirectX/graphics based  architecture makes GDI that much smoother on either platform...